# Questions with low number of views

Tags: discussion, questions, quality-improvement

I have posted following question on Stack Overflow

[Numeric Keyboard not showing on Webview TextBox focus Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368217/numeric-keyboard-not-showing-on-webview-textbox-focus-android)

It attracted very low number of views. I don't know about quality of the question but the number of answers and comments is low.

Is there any drop in quality of question that I have posted or is there something else which has affected the view count or is there any general help guidelines on writing good questions which would getting better answers?

Can anyone tell me why? Or give me some tips to improve my question?

Comment: Well, it will get a couple of views more because of the meta-effect ...

Comment: I think you should have added a related code snippet in your question. It seems a bit broad currently.

Comment: @AzizShaikh I have many questions which attached low numbers of views. do i need to narrate question properly?

Comment: Yes you should, anything that explains your objective of posting this meta question. Probably you are asking for general help on writing good questions which would getting better answers. Is that the case?

Comment: @AzizShaikh yes